# What fastener to affix 2x6 support to 16" deep 16'L lvl?

Tags: wood, woodworking, construction, beam, support

I am building a temp support wall using 16" lvl and 4 built up 2x6's on each end for support "legs".

What fastener would be best suited to join a single 2x6 to the face of a 3.5" 2 ply lvl beam?

And what fastener would be best to affix the two 2x6's together?

(The second 2x6 will be fastened to the first by face and cut shorter to sit beneath the beam and act as a column while the first will extend parallel to the face of the beam and be affixed to the beam)

For reference I have on-hand:

3" #10 DSV decking screws from simpson,

3-1/4" .148 smooth shank nails

3" .131 smooth shank nails

A pack of everbilt exterior #10 2-1/2" screws.

Edit: Photo added

https://imgur.com/gallery/EjYruGm

Comment: Probably does not matter that much.  You are only using them to hold the wood together, not to actually hold the wood up.  I would add a second short 2x6 under the beam so it is completely supported.

Comment: Fair. If you reference my photo, another 2x6 arrangement will go on the back side of the lvl to mirror the one in the pic. I'm wary of the sheer load compressing whenever fastener I use when I remove the material lift that's supporting it now. The taller 2x6 would be bearing some weight I should think